# Populating a google sheet using apps script after receiving data from Postman

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, postman

So I am trying to fill a google sheet using apps script. I am supposed to receive a JSON object from Postman through POST. The object will appear as such:

```
{
     "email":"jdoe@gmail.com",
     "full_name": "John Doe",
     "score": 4.0,
     "max_score": 5.0
     "attempt_starttime": "2021-09-21T03:28:13+0000",
     "attempt_endtime":"2021-09-21T03:28:35+0000",
     "invited_on":"2021-09-21T03:27:50+0000",
     "percentage_score":100.0,
}
```

We are assuming that it will always be in this format and order without fail.
The data is then modified and put into this sheet:
[Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsWW6.png)

I would like help on how to populate the sheet with just the data from the JSON object first as I am failing at that. I believe I can modify it for my purpose from there. I would aslo like to know how I can convert the timestamps into days of weeks and do subtraction on them as well. I am new to both Apps Script and Postman so any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

This is what I have so far:

```
function doPost(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  const headers = ws.getRange(1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  const dataHeaders = headers.slice()
  const body = e.postData.contents;
  const jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
  const data = dataHeaders.map(h => jsonBody[h]);
  ws.appendRow(data);
}
```

Comment: When I saw your Spreadsheet from the image, it seems that the header values are different from the object you want to send. I think that this might be the reason for your issue. How about modifying the header values with the keys of the value you want to put? Or, how about creating an object for replacing the header values and the keys?

Comment: Your json in uncorrect, there is a lack of comma after max_score and an extra comma after percentage_score!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the headers as is, **add a line before your current headers with the exact spelling**, i.e. : *full_name, email, score, max_score, attempt_starttime, attempt_endtime, invited_on, percentage_score* and correct your json (fix commas situation) ...

For instance

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  const dataHeaders = ws.getRange(1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  const body = `{
     "email":"jdoe@gmail.com",
     "full_name": "John Doe",
     "score": 4.0,
     "max_score": 5.0,
     "attempt_starttime": "2021-09-21T03:28:13+0000",
     "attempt_endtime":"2021-09-21T03:28:35+0000",
     "invited_on":"2021-09-21T03:27:50+0000",
     "percentage_score":100.0
}`
  const jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
  const data = dataHeaders.map(h => jsonBody[h]);
  ws.appendRow(data);
}
```

works fine
[image]